# How to send HABTM as JSON in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I am currently working on a recipe app that uses Ember on the frontend and a Rails API on the back. In Rails I have a has and belongs to many relationship between recipes and ingredients. My ingredients model not only stores the ingredient name, but nutritional information so I am not able to simple store ingredients as an array field on recipes.

I am currently confused about how I should set up my Rails API to send properly formatted JSON. According to this

[website](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/)

Ember expects JSON to be formatted something like this: [image]

Assuming this is correct, how should I achieve this in my Rails API?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar issue, I solved this from my recipe serializer similar to this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010544/rails-active-model-serializer-has-many-and-accessing-the-parent-record)

Answer (score 0):

I use active_model_serializers (0.10.2) and Rails 5:

```
class RecipeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :time, :yield, :servings, :url

  has_many :ingredients # not HABTM here!
end
```

PUT http://localhost:3000/api/recipes/2 this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "recipes",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test",
      "time" : "test2",
      "ingredients_ids": [1]
    }
  }
}
```