# Pass rails method(association) to React Js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, associations, ruby-on-rails-5

In My React js application I need to pass data of my `Product` Model's association model(say `"Taxon"`),i am doing it successfully using `Active record serializer` as

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(object, options).serializable_hash
```

where i pass `options` as all association relation.
i can get whole array of taxon objects as json,But I want something mentioned As following

i using rails as backed i am calling method like

```
Prodct.first.category.name
```

which gives  => `"mugs"`

the method it calls is

```
def category
  taxons.joins(:taxonomy).find_by(spree_taxonomies: { name: Spree.t(:taxonomy_categories_name) })
end
```

Which give specific taxon object,In rails its working fine

But i need to pass it  to `React` As json object(i am using React and Redux in front end)

Please help me to solve this..
 let me know if i can provide any required information...

**Edit**

My Product Serilizer class

```
class ProductSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
attributes :id, :slug, :name, :description

has_one :master
has_many :images
has_many :variants
has_many :product_properties
has_many :taxons // Can I change something here.....?
```

end
end

Comment: just render it as a json, `render json: {taxon: taxon, success: true}`

Comment: @PraveshKhatri i am getting taxon object already  but i need to call a category method while using ARS

Comment: if you want to call `category` method from react then you need to call route from react and after completing the manipulation just render it from your category method, like above

Comment: @PraveshKhatri That's also one possible way but what if i want as a product object..

Comment: please tell me `Prodct.first.category.name` how is this is a method. you need to provide more details with your respective controller, routes and model

Comment: I am using Spree so you can refer https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/taxon.rb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145199/discussion-between-pravesh-khatri-and-anish).